# Julia - equivalent of R's rep() with times argument

Tags: vector, julia

I am looking for an idiomatic and compact way to achieve in Julia what I would do in R with

```
v1=1:5;v2=5:1;out=rep(v1,times=v2);out
# 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

i.e. replicate each element in vector `v1` a number of times given by the corresponding element in vector `v2`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [VectorizedRoutines.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/VectorizedRoutines.jl):

```
# Pkg.clone("https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/VectorizedRoutines.jl")
# Will be Pkg.add("VectorizedRoutines") after being added to package system
using VectorizedRoutines
v1=1:5
v2 = 5:-1:1
R.rep(v1,each = v2)
```

The implementation is based off of RLEVectors.jl via the suggestion of aireties (improved the typing a bit so you don't have to collect).

This is a package I started up to get together all the vectorized routines from R/MATLAB/Python so that porting functions (and ideas) easier to Julia. Feel free to open issues on the Github repository for suggestions of functions to implement, functions implemented in other packages I should know about, syntax not matching other languages, or if there are any other problems. Also feel free to give a pull request if you implement any functions like this. If you need help, don't be afraid make a pull request with the basic function and I can help you out.

Comment: Many thanks for that - this is indeed way faster and much more memory efficient!

Comment: If you would have time would you also mind taking a quick peek at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134926/benchmarks-of-technical-programming-languages-r-julia-mathematica-matlab-fo - I did an R to Julia port there of a little example program but I am getting poor benchmark results in Julia - you would probably be able to tell me right away what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using array comprehensions:

```
v1 = 1:5;
v2 = 5:-1:1;

out = vcat([ [v1[idx] for n = 1:v2[idx]] for idx = 1:length(v1) ]...)
```

Also, if you want something closer to the R syntax, you can use the `rep()` function from the RLEVectors package:

```
## Pkg.add("RLEVectors")
using RLEVectors
out2 = rep(collect(v1), each = collect(v2))
```

As is, `out2` will be a vector with Run Length Encoding.  It will function similarly to most other vectors as is, with memory and computation speedups in some cases.  But, if you want a regular vector from it, just use `collect(out2)`.

Comment: Many thanks for that - much appreciated! Only just learning Julia here...

Comment: @TomWenseleers Sure thing.  See also my updated answer, with another option that may be closer to the R syntax you're familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `fill.`.

```
vcat(fill.(1:5, 5:-1:1)...)'
#1×15 adjoint(::Vector{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
# 1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  5
```

Or using `inverse_rle` from `StatsBase`.

```
using StatsBase
inverse_rle(1:5, 5:-1:1)'
#1×15 adjoint(::Vector{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
# 1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  5
```